# Best practice in dealing with group of objects?

Tags: oop

You have a Page class. This class naturally has all the methods and variables to deal with single page objects, create(), update(), delete(), and so on.

From an OOP architecture stand point, what would be the best practice for dealing with a significant number of manipulators for groups of this object?

Large quantities of operations such as : listAllPages(), getRecentPages(), getTop10Pages(), deleteAllPagesFromAuthor()

A few points to consider :

- Since we are dealing with multiples, it would not make sens to put those methods in the class... after all, it would not be logical for a single page to manipulate all the other pages.
- On the other hand, making all these operations into separate, "free floating" helper functions would be disorganized. **That's what I usually do** if i have only a couple of functions, but when I get a large quantity of them I keep thinking there must be a better OOP way to keep things organized logically.
- I thought about creating a "Pages" class (plural), but I am not sure if structuring my application to consider plural of an object as an object makes sens on the long term.

Is there a best practice in this area? Or to be specific, what would be the optimal way to implement those group helpers for my Page object?

Comment: Note to editors : I do not think this question is subjective. After all we have big applications that deal with multiple pages, news, forum posts, and so on repeatedly so the answer must exist. Also my question is very specific to my Page class example with a large quantity of helper functions, I believe there is such thing as a best answer for this question. It might be keeping them as functions, creating a class, or even using some OOP concepts I am not aware of.

Comment: "but I am not sure if structuring my application to consider plural of an object as an object makes sens on the long term" Why do you think it might not make sense? What would be wrong with this in specific. It's called a collection and there isn't much wrong with it.

Comment: `PageManager` comes to mind. Or `Blog`, or whatever your collection  of pages is part of.

Comment: By Collection do you mean just a simple class that holds these methods, or do you mean a specific language construct? I use PHP and I am not aware of any implementation of collection OOP models in the language.